# How to count number of 2-star or wedge in a graph or network using igraph package in R

Tags: r, igraph

The `igraph` package provides very efficient counting for the number of triangles in a graph or network, that is `count_triangles()` function.

I'm unable to find the source code of that function using `getAnywhere` since a small modification over that function will give me the 2-star count, I'm speculating that.

Is there any fast algorithm to find a 2-star or wedge count from a graph?

Suppose we want to find the number of wedges from the following graph

```
w3 <- matrix(c(c(0,1,1,1), c(1,0,1,0), c(1,1,0,0), c(1,0,0,0)), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
w21 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(w3, mode = "undirected")
```

The results for triangle count are the following
for the small graphs like `w3`

```
triangle_cnt <- function(adj_mat){
  return(sum(diag(adj_mat %*% adj_mat %*% adj_mat)))
}# triangle count function

triangle_cnt.igraph <- function(adj_mat){
  adg_mat <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_mat)
  return(sum(count_triangles(adg_mat)) * 2)
}# triangle count function
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(triangle_cnt(w3), triangle_cnt.igraph(w3))
```

Output

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(triangle_cnt(w3), triangle_cnt.igraph(w3))
Unit: microseconds
                    expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
        triangle_cnt(w3)  1.435  1.640  2.06394   2.05  2.1730  14.104   100
 triangle_cnt.igraph(w3) 57.400 58.999 63.25521  59.86 62.3815 254.692   100
```

But for large graphs with 1000+ nodes, the following performance change drastically

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(triangle_cnt(adj_mat), triangle_cnt.igraph(adj_mat))
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        triangle_cnt(adj_mat) 651.1529 660.7670 669.5889 663.1095 665.9754 753.3584   100
 triangle_cnt.igraph(adj_mat) 180.1882 181.3038 195.4430 181.9534 182.6366 524.7692   100
```

Where `adj_mat` is an adjacency matrix of a graph with 1000 nodes. You can generate using any model.

Similarly, I have the following code for the wedge count in a network.

```
wedge_cnt <- function(adj_mat){
  return(sum(adj_mat %*% adj_mat))
}#Wedge count function
```

But it is way slower for the large network as we expected. Any kind of modification is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm unable to find the source code of that function using getAnywhere since a small modification over that function will give me the 2-star count, I'm speculating that.

It's here, but I really don't think it's what you want ...

https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/b4a65cfb83f110e0102bdeef70cca42da99f3010/src/properties/triangles.c#L426

> Is there any fast algorithm to find a 2-star or wedge count from a graph?

You can use igraph's motif counter. Example:

```
> set.seed(123)
> g<-sample_gnm(10,20)
> motifs(g,3)
[1] NA NA 39 12
```

There are 39 two-stars and 12 triangles. Note that these are counted as [induced subgraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph).

---

You propose using `sum(A^2)` for the two-star count where `A` is the adjacency matrix. There are several issues with this:

- The diagonal should be excluded. Since `Tr(A^2)` is twice the edge count, you can just subtract that.
- This method is counting every two-star twice, so we need the correction `sum(A^2)/2 - E`, where `E` is the edge count.
- This method is counting all subgraphs, not just induced ones. It will count 3 two-stars in each triangle. So we must subtract the number of triangles.

The correct formula for the number of induced two-stars is

```
sum(A^2) / 2 - Tr(A^3) / 2 - E
```

The formula for the number of triangles is

```
Tr(A^3) / 6
```

This is a reasonably efficient method for large graphs for as long as you are working with sparse matrices.

One more tip: To verify your counting, you can use `count_subgraph_isomorphisms` with `induced=TRUE` or `induced=FALSE`. The default is `FALSE`. This method also overcounts by a factor of `count_automorphisms(pattern)`. This won't be very efficient, but it can give you confidence when you are developing other counting methods.

Comment: `igraph` motif counter function is very slow for the large matrices. Is there any alternative for finding wedge count? The `count_triangles()` function is a bit faster than the usual procedure.